# Issue with NMaxValue Constrained to an ImplicitRegion

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions

I am trying to find the maximum (and minimum) value of an interpolated function constrained to an ImplictRegion with a (partly) curved boundary. I have followed the documentation carefully and tried two options suggested therein. They both seem to fail with the same issue. Below is some test code and output which illustrate the problem. I am in MMA 12.0.0.

```
h[x_] = 1/(1 + x^2);
yMnSlv = 0;
rng = 12;
regSlv = ImplicitRegion[{y > h[x]}, {{x, -rng, rng}, {y, yMnSlv, 
    rng}}]; psi = 
 NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == h[x]], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == y, x == -rng], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == y, x == rng], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == y, y == rng]}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] regSlv, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 14];
{xMn, xMx, yMn, yMx} = {-4, 4, 0, 2.5};
vy = Evaluate[-D[psi[x, y], x]];
regPl = ImplicitRegion[{y > h[x]}, {{x, xMn, xMx}, {y, yMn, yMx}}];
Print[Show[RegionPlot[regPl]]];
max = NMaxValue[vy, {x, y} \[Element] regPl]
Print[Show[RegionPlot[regPl], 
   Graphics[Point[ {-2.7238221935187372, 0.008194367706853735}]]]];
```

Here is the output:

[image]

The first plot above just shows the defined region, while the second has included the point which yields the warning message, and verifies that it is clearly outside the defined region. So, why is the code searching in the region outside the defined one?
Finally, I have verified that the prescription used does work with an ordinary function, as opposed to the Differentiated InterpolatedFunction used here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `vy=..` to a pure function

```
j[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[-Derivative[1, 0][psi][x, y]]
```

`NMaximize` gives the complete solution

```
maxi = NMaximize[j[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] regPl]
(*{0.418163, {x -> -0.91878, y -> 0.881249}}*)
```

Unfortunaely this maximum isn't very accurate.

**workaround**
The solution `NDSolveValue` uses `FiniteElement`, further calculation of the result, especially derivatives, should lie on the grid!.

```
h[x_] = 1/(1 + x^2);
yMnSlv = 0;
rng = 12/3;
regSlv = ImplicitRegion[{y >= h[x]}, {{x, -rng,rng}, {y, yMnSlv,rng}}];     
psi = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y],y, y] == 0, 
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == h[x]], 
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == y, x == -rng], 
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == y, x == rng], 
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == y, y == rng]}, 
u, {x, y} \[Element] regSlv , Method ->{"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}];
```

now the maximum of `vy` can be determined (at the gridpoints)

```
pi = psi["Grid"];(*grid *)
vy[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[-Derivative[1, 0][psi][x, y]]
pi3D = Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], Apply[vy , #]} &, pi];
piMax = MaximalBy[%, Last ][[1]]
(*{-0.423516, 0.847913, 0.845254} *)

Show[{ListPointPlot3D[pi3D],Graphics3D[{Red,PointSize[Large],Point[piMax ]}]},PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ulirich Neumann. But that does not fix it. Since you omit the minus sign, you are calculating the minimum of the function, which happens not to experience the same problem. ie, for the minimum, it works the original way too. But if one inserts the minus sign, one still gets problems. The error message in that case is:

Comment: The new error message is: NMaxValue::nnum: The function value -(-InterpolatingFunction[{{-12.,12.},{0.00689655,12.}},{5,4225,0,{926205,0},{3,3},{1,0},0,0,0,Indeterminate&,{},{},False},{<<1>>},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<3>>,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<926155>>},{Automatic}])[<<1>>] is not a number at {x,y} = {1.06456,1.28933}.

Comment: I see that the new problematic point has different problems. The error above is produced for a point which is now inside the relevant region, so the issue must be a different one here.

Comment: Sorry for missing the "minus"., I corrected my answer. Hope it might help.

Comment: Thanks @Ulirich Neumann. That solution seems to work perfectly!

Comment: On further inspection, this does not in fact fix the problem. There are two evidences of problems: 1). We still get an error: NMinimize::nnum: The function value Indeterminate is not a number at {x,y} = {-2.72382,0.00819437}. 2). The found maximum is nowhere near the maximum. In fact, since our function is of odd symmetry, the mirror solution of the minimum is the maximum, ie. +0.760 rather than the value found of +0.418. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulHarrison Which Mathematica version do you use? I don't get an error, but maximum I found is only near the global maximum.

Comment: @PaulHarrison Look at my  modified answer

Comment: @Ulirich Neumann Also, your found maximum is around -0.42, but I know that the maximum of this function is close to 0.8, so the value is completely wrong. The 3D plot shows it correctly, I believe.

Comment: @PaulHarrison "My" maximum is around `.84`, not so bad I think.

Comment: @Ulirich Neumann Ah yes.Thanks for the clarification. I was (mis)interpreting the order of reported values as {max,xval,yval}, as before with NMaximize, but I see now that it is {xval,yval,max}, so it is good. My mistake.

Comment: @Ulirich Neumann Thanks for all your help with this. It all seems good now. Best Wishes.

Comment: @PaulHarrison You're welcome!